# No connection error when attempting to connect to a stateful set Mongodb Kubernetes deployment

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, gcloud

I have the following service...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    port: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mongo
```

And the following stateful set...

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: mongo
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
            - "--smallfiles"
            - "--noprealloc"
          ports:
            - name: mongo
              containerPort: 27017
        - name: mongo-sidecar
          image: cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar
          env:
            - name: "VERSION"
              value: "2"
            - name: MONGO_SIDECAR_POD_LABELS
              value: "role=mongo"
```

However, my code can't make a connection, using the url `mongo:27017`. I've tried connecting to `mongo`, `mongo-0.mongo:27017`, loads of others. If I exec into a container and run `$ nslookup mongo` I get...

```
Name:      mongo
Address 1: 10.1.0.80 mongo-0.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 10.1.0.81 mongo-1.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 3: 10.1.0.82 mongo-2.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Hitting `$ curl mongo:27017` or `$ telnet mongo 27017` gives me a connection refused error.

Comment: `telnet mongo 27017` is the correct syntax

Comment: are you running telnet or curl in the app container?

Comment: @FarhadFarahi same error with the correct telnet call, and yeah that's from the app container.

Comment: can you verify on mongo containers that they are listening on 27017? using telnet, ss or netstat

Comment: @FarhadFarahi if I exec into the mongo container, telnet localhost 27017, it does connect. If I run netstat, it shows a bunch of stuff running on 27017.

Comment: use `netstat -tlpn`  then look at the ip before :27017, is it 0.0.0.0 ? I am making sure that mongo isnt listening on the localhost, hence the problem you are facing.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi Local address: 127.0.0.1:27017 then foreign address 0.0.0.0:*

Comment: I believe thats the problem, you should have local address of 0.0.0.0:27017, there is a setting in mongo db configuration named bind which controls this.

Comment: `net:
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
   port: 27017`

Comment: @FarhadFarahi 've tried this, I'm still getting: Error connecting to datastore mongo:27017: no reachable servers from my go app, when attempting to connect to mongo:27017. If I curl mongo:27017 from another container, I get curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer now instead of a generic can't connect error like I had before. So feels a little bit closer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `bind_ip` to command:

```
      command:
        - mongod
        - "--replSet"
        - rs0
        - "--smallfiles"
        - "--noprealloc"          
        - "--bind_ip"
        - "0.0.0.0"
```

This [option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#core-options) tells the monogodb daemon to listen on all IPv4 addresses, rather than the default of `localhost`.

Comment: I've tried this, I'm still getting: `Error connecting to datastore mongo:27017: no reachable servers` from my go app, when attempting to connect to `mongo:27017`. 

If I curl `mongo:27017` from another container, I get `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` now instead of a generic can't connect error like I had before. So feels a little bit closer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I fixed this, it was a case of setting the bind_ip=0.0.0.0, but it was also that I had to change the selector in my service to `role: mongo` instead if `app: mongo`. Then in my deployment I had to include `role: mongo` in my metadata, like...

```
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
        role: mongo
```